# Linux and Ethernet 2 VSDL converter: do I need a driver?

Tags: dsl, pppoe

I have bought a [Planet VC-231 Ethernet over VDSL2](https://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/vc-231) converter an I am trying to connect to my provider (O2.CZ), who uses ATM (encapsulation LLC) and PPPoE. I found, that I should start `br2684ctl` first. However that fails:

```
br2684ctl[796]: Interface "nas1" created sucessfully
br2684ctl[796]: Communicating over ATM 0.8.48, encapsulation: LLC
br2684ctl[796]: Fatal: failed to connect on socket; No such device
```

This message should mean, that there is no modem connected. Do I miss some driver? Kernel module? Is it ever possible? The box is connected with a RJ45 to computer as well as other devices in ehternet. I tried the `pppoeconf` utility, but it does neither find any suitable device/connection.

When I would have a PCI or USB modem, I would understand, that I am missing some driver, but driver for *Ethernet2whatever* converter? I don't expect such driver. I am right, please?

Comment: But then by the same logic you shouldn't be needing br2684ctl either (or other chipset-specific tools). What is the command supposed to achieve?

Comment: To dial the PPPoE connection. I've studied a bit. I suppose now, that encaptulation is a part of the Ethernet standard (so no br2684ctl needed). And there is really no driver for converter, neither any detection, because it is just connected or disconnected - data reach or don't reach the target. I think, I begin to understand the topic. Provider uses VLAN ID 848 and this so called tagging is also a part of Ethernet. When wrong, it can probably not connect. It is - I suppose - to configure VLAN ID first, then try to dial the PPPoE connection. I'l see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is no.** Converter is really a low-level hardware somewhere between you and the opposite end-point. There may be more of them on the link, but you don't care. For the machine is the connection easily an usual Ethernet connection. It doesn't see, that after few centimeter is Ethernet converted to VDSL, coax, optic or whatever.

Ad `br2684ctl`: this software is supposed to get applied, if the converter is connected to the system bus as an external USB modem or an internal PCI card. Such hardware is a part of computer and you do then need some driver. If any device has not been found, `br2684ctl` puts out the message above: `no such device`. That is even the case here, because converter is not visible for the system.